# Node.js accessing elements from within the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm performing a get request to local server at http://localhost:3000.

I'm processing the request.body (JSON data array) through Node.JS command line.

I just want to get the name element and not the other two elements. I tried giving the index, but it didn't work.

```
http://localhost:3000
[ { name: 'Ankit', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 0 },
  { name: 'Nikhil', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 3 },
  { name: 'Ajay', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 4 },
  { name: 'Vineet', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 5 } ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can filter out the names using map function. see below.

```
    var obj = [
           {name: 'Ankit', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 0},
           {name: 'Nikhil', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 3},
           {name: 'Ajay', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 4},
           {name: 'Vineet', drag: true, jqyoui_pos: 5}
       ];


    var result = obj.map(function(a) {return a.name;});

    console.log(result);
```